# Admin routing compatibility mode for extensions in not available in Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: admin, extensions, security, routing, ce-1.9.2.2

I have upgraded magento to 1.9.2.2, i wanted to confirm will it also install all patches including SUPEE-6788 by default..?
or we have to install SUPEE-6788 seperately in magento 1.9.2.2  ?

Comment: SUPEE-6788 is included in 1.9.2.2, you do not need to install it, or even can't, on a Magento 1.9.2.2. Please take a look at http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.2.html

Comment: ok in "SUPEE-6788" we have given an option i.e. "Admin routing compatibility mode for extensions" in System > Config > Advanced > Admin > Security
But i couldnot see that option in 1.9.2.2 magento..
Why is it so..?

Comment: Sounds strange, you should have the settings `Admin routing compatibility mode for extensions` - did your upgrade went well? Have you cleared the cache? What does the current version says in the back end footer?

Comment: In footer it shows magento version "Magento ver. 1.9.2.2"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Magento 1.9.2.2. includes the SUPEE-6788 patch bundle.
If you upgraded to Magento 1.9.2.2 your installation is fine so far.

See also the official resources for some more information:

> SUPEE-6788 Patch Bundle
>
> This patch bundle protects your Magento installation against several
>   potential threats, and includes a new configuration setting that helps
>   manage the backward compatibility of the patch for extensions and
>   customizations. The first patch in the bundle was included in the
>   Magento Community 1.9.2.1 release. However, versions of Magento
>   Community prior to 1.9.2.1 need this critical patch.

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.2.html